# MongoDB: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017, No connection could be made because target machine actively refused it

Tags: mongodb

I've been using Mongo for a while now, and I never had any kind of errors. But today, I tried running the mongo command in my terminal and I got the following error:

> Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. :

I have my PATH variable for Mongo properly configured in my environment variables as follows:

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin
```

so I doubt that is the issue. I remember going through my task manager yesterday and I accidentally terminated a program running in the background related to Mongo, but I can't seem to remember exactly what it was called, and I really think that that's the root of my problem, because before having terminated that Mongo program in my task manager I had never ran across this connection problem before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By terminating a program in the background, I'm going to assume you didn't just end process, otherwise a simple computer restart would fix your issue. And in some cases, that same program would've relaunched when you launched MongoDB. But if you *disabled* a service and  need to find which service needs to be running to be able to connect to your MongDB then I would suggest going through your Windows Services list and seeing which ones you disabled and looking one relating to TCP or SNMP.

This is because MongoDB Wire Protocol is a simple socket-based, request-response style protocol. You communicate with the database server through a regular TCP/IP socket and since you can't remember which one you "terminated" and any number of services related to networking can cause a dependency to be absent, I can't be more specific in helping you determine which one you need to turn back on and you'll have to do it through trial and error but I can at least offer you some guidance, hopefully.

Specifically you can either

Run system configuration using

```
msconfig
```

In a run box, navigating to the Services tab, order the list by Date Disabled to find the service that was disabled which correlates with when you when snooping through task manager, or

Run Task manager and navigate to the Services Tab, then Open Services, and order them by Status or by Name, and look for any service that includes TCP/IP, COM+, Port direction, etc. to see which one is disabled and change the configuration from anything but Disabled and then stat it manually and run MongDB again.

It's about as specific as I can get without knowing anything more than you terminated some program running in the background but I hope it helps.

Comment: The target actively refusing a connection can be a result of a dependency missing for recognizing access to the port is the speculation that my answer is based on

Answer (score 0):

The background process (daemon) for MongoDB is called 'mongod'. It's an executable in your bin directory inside your mongodb installation. You can just execute it in the terminal.

Run:
`C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin\mongod.exe`

Comment: I ran mongod but I'm still getting the same error as before. I'm using Git Bash as my terminal if that helps at all.

Comment: An additional part of the error is that it is a SocketException

Comment: Try opening another terminal and running the command: mongo

Comment: Yeah I tried running mongo in my terminal but that is where the error is coming from. When I type mongo into my terminal I get the error that I posted above.

Comment: Ah right .. you might need to set your db data dir again .. You run mongod with the dbpath flag....  mongod -dbpath c:\data\db  .. that's the default path, adjust if you've set it somewhere else

Comment: Currently my data path is C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\data. Should I change it to c:\data ?

Comment: Nah just run mongod -dbpath C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\data and run mongo  again

Answer (score 0):

You will have to download the Mongodb Shell and change the environmental variables. The steps are listed below:

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/install/

Install from .zip File
Open the MongoDB Shell download page.
Open the MongoDB Download Center.

Download the mongosh installation archive for your operating system.
Download the appropriate version of mongosh for your operating system. MongoDB also provides versions of mongosh that use the system's OpenSSL installation. For details, see the MongoDB Download Center.

3 Extract the files from the downloaded archive.

4 Add the mongosh binary to your PATH environment variable.
Ensure that the extracted MongoDB Shell binary is in the desired location in your filesystem, then add that location to your PATH environment variable.

To add the MongoDB Shell binary's location to your PATH environment variable:

Open the Control Panel.

In the System and Security category, click System.

Click Advanced system settings. The System Properties modal displays.

Click Environment Variables.

In the System variables section, select Path and click Edit. The Edit environment variable modal displays.

Click New and add the filepath to your mongosh binary (executable file).

Click OK to confirm your changes. On each other modal, click OK to confirm your changes.

To confirm that your PATH environment variable is correctly configured to find mongosh, open a command prompt and enter the mongosh --help command. If your PATH is configured correctly, a list of valid commands displays.

First in hyper terminal type mongod hit enter.

Second hit press t + shift and cntrl at the same time to go to a new terminal.

Next type mongosh "mongodb://localhost:27017"